# UnauthorizedAccessException - The image location is not under specified directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8.5

I am copying a web site, written in asp .NET, from a windows server 2003 machine to a windows server 2012 with IIS 8.5.

The web site is working great on the old machine, but no charts are displayed in any of my webpages on the new machine.

I get a strange error:

```
    General Information
--------------------------------
MachineName: AYEVENS12MAVTST
TimeStamp: 10/08/2014 11:38:18
WindowsIdentity: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Exception Information
---------------------------------------
Exception Type: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Message: The image location is not under specified directory.
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: Void ValidateUri(System.String)
HelpLink: NULL
Source: System.Web.DataVisualization
HResult: -2147024891

StackTrace Information
---------------------------------------
   at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandlerSettings.ValidateUri(String key)
   at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.DefaultImageHandler.System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.IChartStorageHandler.Load(String key)
   at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler.ProcessSavedChartImage(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

This is weird since I see the path of the picture is correct and I can open the picture with no problem.
I thought it's a permission problem but I gave full control of the containing folder to IIS_USRS and to WindowsIdentity: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM and the same error keeps popping up. 
What troubles me is the message "The image location is not under specified directory." since the image is where it's supposed to be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to impersonate a specific authorized windows account using the web.config file ?

```
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <identity impersonate="true" userName="user name" password=" user password" />
      </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Are you really sure that it works well in your localhost machine ? If yes then you should check the IIS 8.5 setting in your Windows Server 2012 .

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved it by (accidently) removing the line

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;privateImages=false;timeout=600;dir=c://TempImageFiles;deleteAfterServicing=false;" />
```

from the webconfig, I have no idea why this works.